# How to retrieve a list using jQuery.get() method in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have this page, basically on a button click, I want to retrieve a list from another HTML file (or ASP or PHP, whatever) and add it to a list I already have. I'm just not sure how to go about doing this. Any ideas?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>autocomplete demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var tags = [ "String1", "String2", "String3" ];
            $("button").click(function() {
                $.get("test.html", function(data, status) {

                   <!-- This is where I want to get the list -->
                   <!-- something like: tags.add(list from test.html) -->

                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <button>Click me</button>

    <div id="result">hello world</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Also, if can anyone provide a simple HTML page that will create a list of dummy strings for me to test it with? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by list? Is it an <ul><li>... in the other html you want to get?

Comment: Yes this is what I want to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ok, I thought so.

You can do it with get like this:

```
$.get("test.html", function (data, status) {
    $(data).filter("#id_of_ul_for_example").find("li").each(function () {
        var val = $(this).text();
        tags.push(val);
    });
});
```

In this fiddle I had to use post instead of get, because of jsFiddle ajax request...
http://jsfiddle.net/vxm1ugee/2/

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you really get a list of values you have to convert your list to array first by using

```
tags2 = "String4,String5,String6".split(",");
```

and then javascript's concat method

```
result = tags.concat(tags2);
```

Comment: It will be an HTML list in this format... <ul><li>...

Comment: What would you actually like to do? Would you like to read text within <li></li> tags?

Comment: yeah, I have a list of Strings within <li></li> tags on an HTML file. Now, I want to load all of those strings into my tags array